# DynamicLinks.API is not available on this device

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented Dynamics Links in my instant app, when click in link open the instant app but in to method getDynamicLink(intent) it shows me the following error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: DynamicLinks.API is not available on this device.
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzg.zzu(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zze.zzt(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzx(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzad.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzj(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzv(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzakh(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The code in my class is the following:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this)
            {
                pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                var deepLink: Uri? = null
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                }


                showAlertDialog(deepLink.toString())
                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                // account.
                // ...

                // ...
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e -> Log.w("FailureListener", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e) }
```

Please help me.

Comment: I think this might mean that it is in fact not available, have you contacted the Firebase support?

Comment: What device are you using? What is GMS Core version? Does device have Google Play services?

Comment: @bugs  There is no questions in stackoverflow that mention "DynamicLinks.API is not available on this device.". How the question you linked as original-duplicate will help people to fix this problem?

Comment: @oleksiy check the revisions.

Comment: I have the same issue: 17: API: DynamicLinks.API is not available on this device.
How did you solved it?

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate?